# Using numeric constant in macro function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, avr

I'm writing a simple library for my AVR, and I wanted to try to use a macro function to define my baud-rate.  A lot of the functions in the AVR's library use the macro F_CPU as well as the one I want to write.

Here's what I have for the macro definition and my supposed implementation:

```
#define BAUD_SELECT(baud) ((F_CPU)/(2*baud)-1)

myubrr = BAUD_SELECT(38400);
```

I have tried using #define F_CPU 8000000UL, and also in the make file as -D"F_CPU 8000000UL" but I always get the same error at the implementation line.

```
expected ')' before numeric constant
```

I'm sure it has something to do with my abuse of #define, and that the macro definition is in a header file, the implementation in the appropriate .c file, and the F_CPU definition either in the makefile or another main.c file.

*EDIT*
I made the parenthesis change as suggested and ran the preprocessor and found the output file (atleast I think)

```
 unsigned int myubrr = ((8000000UL 1)/(2*(baud))-1);
```

It places an extra 1 where F_CPU should be, I'm not experienced with the preprocessor so I'm not sure how to make it not do that, but perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: try running the preprocessor on it and see what it expands to

Comment: This seems to be correct. You are most certainly missing a parenthesis somewhere else. On a side note, in the expression of the macro, always put the variables taken as argument in parentheses. Imagine your macro called like `BAUD_SELECT(some_baud+100)` which would expand to `((F_CPU)/(2*some_baud+100)-1)` which is not what you want. So, you would have to write the expression like this: `((F_CPU)/(2*(baud))-1)`

Comment: Take a closer look at the defintion of F_CPU ... perhaps there is some garbage at the end of the line outside your editor's window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
#define BAUD_SELECT(baud) ((F_CPU)/(2*(baud))-1)

unsigned int myubrr = BAUD_SELECT(38400);
```

when I compile with

```
$ cc -c -DF_CPU=8000000UL t.c
```

The extra parens don't really matter in this specific case, thought they're a good idea in general.  So there's something else going on.  Perhaps there's another definition of `F_CPU` in some other header file that is overriding your definition of `F_CPU`

Comment: Strangely enough going from -D"F_CPU 8000000UL" to -D"F_CPU=8000000UL" allowed it to compile, I never noticed any distinction between the two until now, but still not sure what the preprocessor does differently.

Comment: Indeed, this is somehow weird ... ;-) - In the first run -D"F_CPU 8000000UL" defines *one* macro with a blank in it's identifier, namely the macro 'F_CPU 8000000UL', as no '=' sign is used it gets the value of 1. So we have 'F_CPU 8000000UL 1'. Then when parsing your code the preprocesser does take this phrase as it is and replaces 'F_CPU' in your code with '8000000UL 1'. One could consider this as a cpp bug? ;->

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in parentheses:

```
#define BAUD_SELECT(baud) ((F_CPU)/(2*(baud))-1)
```